# Ito Integral surjective?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $\Phi\in\mathcal{L}\left(M\right)$ if and only if $\Phi$ is a real predictable process and for every $\left\Vert \Phi\right\Vert_{2,t,M}:=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}\Phi_{s}^2 d\langle M\rangle_{s}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty$.
And let $\mathcal{M}_{2}$ be the space of square integrable right continuous martingales. It is well known by Ito Isometry that the mapping 
$$I_{M}:(\mathcal{L}\left(M\right),\left\Vert .\right\Vert_{2})\rightarrow\left(\mathcal{M}_{2},\left|\left\Vert \right|\right\Vert\right)$$
is injective, where $I_{M}\left(\Phi\right)$ is the Ito Integral of $\Phi$.I would like to know if it is also surjective.

Answer (score 3):

No, in general the mapping is not surjective. Consider for example a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$. The Itô integral $I_B(\Phi)$ is a **continuous** martingale and this means that for any (purely) discontinuous martingale $M$ there does not exist $\Phi \in \mathcal{L}(B)$ such that $I_B(\Phi)=M$.

Let me remark that a vast class of (càdlàg) martingales can be represented as a sum of stochastic integrals with respect to a Brownian motion and a Poisson random measure, respectively. This result is due to Ikeda-Watanabe.

> Let $(M_t)_{t \geq 0} \in \mathcal{M}_2$ a martingale with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ generated by a Lévy process. Then there exists predictable processes $f,g$ as well as a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and a Poisson random measure $N$ such that $$M_t - M_0 = \int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t g(s) \, d\tilde{N}_s$$ where $\tilde{N}$ denotes the compensated Poisson random measure.

Comment: That means that $I_{B}$ is surjective if it maps in $\mathcal{M}_{2,c}$ i.e. the space of square integrable continuous martingales.

That means that the role of Levy Processes in the discontinuous world is the same like that of the Brownian Motion in the continuous world?

Comment: @user114170 Roughly speaking, yes. (In the case of continuous square-integrable martingales we also need an assumption on the filtration; namely, that the filtration is an admissible filtration of a Brownian motion.)